# How to send exactly one Tcp packet unsing netperf/ipperf and confirm using tcpdump about the same?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump

I am trying to find out a way to send exactly one TCP packet and verify this on Rx side that same has been received (no other packet) using tcpdump. I am new to networking world. Hence any help/explaination would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These tools are for performance measurements and not for packet crafting. They always establish a full TCP connection for measurements. Since even a TCP connection with no data transfer consists of 6 packets (initial handshake to establish connection and handshake for connection close) you will not be able to send a single TCP packet using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - configure the Rx side NOT to accept a tcp-ip connection from the Tx side, then attempt a connection from Tx side.  You should see a (single) SYN packet on the Rx side, to which it won't respond.  [Unfortunately, the Tx side will then retry the SYN packet a number of times].